# UIColor in SetStrokeColorWithColor triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS - memory issue?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgcontext, uicolor

I have a large line to draw that the colour changes along the line.

Now and again I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the 4th line of the code there.

I suspect that it is something to do with the autoreleasing of the *tempColor but cannot work out how to get this to work effeiciently and not to crash.

Any ideas?  This crashes on say 1 in 50 runs of this code.

```
                    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
                    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, lastx, lasty);
                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point.x, point.y);
                    UIColor *tempColor  = [self colorForHex:[[heightLocal objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue]];
                    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,tempColor.CGColor);
                    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

                    lastx = point.x;
                    lasty = point.y;
```

EDIT:

Just had a quick play after that suggestion and possibly think it is because heightLocal is not initialized?

I cahnged it to the code here...

```
if(idx > [heightLocal count]){
                            heightVar = 0;  
                            NSLog(@"Made it here");
                        }else {
                            heightVar = [[heightLocal objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
                        }
                        UIColor *tempColor  = [self colorForHex:heightVar];
```

and it gets the same error on the first line.  The if!

heightLocal is initialized using...

```
NSArray *heightLocal = routeGrabInstance.pointHeights;
```

Comment: Are you sure idx is always within heightLocal's count?  Separate out the array call from the colorForHex call for debugging.

Comment: you can try if(!heightLocal || idx>=heightLocal.count)

Comment: Perfect, post as answer and I can accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the array you get with:

```
routeGrabInstance.pointHeights;
```

Is not being retained properly. If it's like many classes it could be returned as autorelease.

Try a :

```
[heightLocal retain]
```

after your

```
NSArray *heightLocal = routeGrabInstance.pointHeights;
```

Comment: Or just `NSArray *heightLocal = [routeGrabInstance.pointHeights retain];` ;-)